# How to escape characters in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig and I am having trouble with loading data to pig.
I have a data like below:

**example.txt**

```
name,id,address,age
basu,1,[73,dvg,india],24
nithi,2,[78,bang,india],24
```

in this, delimiter is the comma(,) and the address field itself contains comma(,). I need to escape those comma's in the address field. please someone help me with this

Thanks in advance
Basu

Comment: Is it possible to have address field enclosed in "" instead of [ ] ? If yes, you can use CSVLoader/ CSVExcelStorage API.

Comment: @Murali Roa than you very much for your suggestion.But the address field may not only enclosed by [] it might  be enclosed by any other special characters like #,$ etc but it would be different from delimiter. Is there any way to do this other than using CSVLoader/CSVExcelStorage as you  told. Please direct me in the right way as I don't have any about this as i am very new to Pig.

Comment: yes it's possible to replace [] with "" as you asked please post the code how to load data using CSVLoader

Comment: Added an answer if we are ok to represent address in "" instead of [].

Answer (score 0):

As per @Basu comments if address can be represented in "" instead of [] then the below approach can be used.

**Pig Script :**

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar; 
student_details = LOAD 'student.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader() AS (name:chararray,id:long,address:chararray, age:long); 
student_address = FOREACH student_details GENERATE address;
DUMP student_address;
```

**Input : student.csv**

```
basu,1,"73,dvg,india",24
nithi,2,"78,bang,india",24
```

**Output : DUMP student_address**

```
(73,dvg,india)
(78,bang,india)
```

We can use either : org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage() or org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader().

Refer the below API links for details

1. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html
2. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html

Comment: Is there any way to do if the escaping character is different rather than ""? Please let me know if there is a solution for this.

Comment: @Basu : If its a CSV file then its better to represent addresss in "". The loaders - CSVExcelStorage or CSVLoader escapes delimiter(',') within "".

Answer (score -1):

There is hardly any way to do this with just pig constructs. But yes you can do this with writing a UDF sort of thing where you can try some sort of logic and handle this, but that is not the best way. The recommended way is to always have control-a(\u0001) delimited files.

Comment: This in no way answers the OP's question.